# I keep getting 'Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds' when trying to view objects and I don't know why

Tags: dataframe, object, view

I am using R version 4.3.1 with R Studio (v2023-09). I am trying to run some old code of mine, but I keep getting the error 'Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds' when I try to view the objects. I haven't changed the data or the code since it last worked for me.

```
> # Load package
> library(Momocs)
> # Import files and create object
> FEPDATA <- import_tps("FEP LM.TPS")
> FEPCLASS <- read.csv("Classifier FEP.csv", header = TRUE)
> FEPLDK <- Ldk(FEPDATA$coo, fac = FEPCLASS)
> # Align landmarks
> align_ldk.gpa = fgProcrustes(FEPLDK, tol=0.1)
iteration:  1   gain: 12034 
iteration:  2   gain: 0.052837 
> 
> View(align_ldk.gpa)
Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

In the global environment, the object is a coo : list 38, so not empty. I have tried Str() and the structure appears normal.

I get the same error with other code and datasets too.

```
# Load package
library(Momocs)
# Import files and create object
FSDATA = import_tps("Flipper shape landmarks.TPS")
FSCLASS = read.csv("Classifier FS.csv", header = TRUE)
# Convert the landmarks to outlines
outlines = Out(FSDATA$coo, fac = FSCLASS)
View(outlines)
Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any help is much appreciated, I don't know hoe t resolve the issue because the data seems to exist but I just cant view it.

I have tried multiple datasets but I always get the same error. I have tried exporting as a PDF with panel() or stack() functions applied. I have tried inspecting the data but I am not sure what is causing the error.